# Horizontal movement of player causes egregious numbers when checking vertical velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Player movement is working (at least somewhat) now, however one issue remains, and that's the insane numbers the `y` velocity of the `Rigidbody2D` on the player. Since the `isGrounded` check I plan to add will use velocity for the sake of stability, this needs to be fixed.
It confuses me, considering the velocity is 0 normally, but whenever moving left or right it changes to said high numbers.

Movement code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerM : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PControls control;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    SpriteRenderer sp;
    Transform tr;
    public float speed = 0f;
    public float speedC;
    public float heightSpeed = 5f;
    public float heightC;
    public bool grounded;

    void Start()
    {
        control = new PControls();
        control.Enable();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sp = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        tr = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rb.position, -Vector2.up);
        Color color = new Color(0, 0, 1.0f);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.down);
        speedC = rb.velocity.magnitude;
        var pos = control.Movement.Move.ReadValue<float>();
        float GetVerticalSpeed() => rb.velocity.y;
        


        

        if(pos == -1)
        {
            sp.flipX = true;
        }
        else if(pos == 1)
        {
            sp.flipX = false;
        }
        
        if((pos == 0) && (speed > 0.1f))
        {
            speed -= 3f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if(speed < 1.4f)
        {
            speed += Mathf.Abs(pos) * 8 * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(speedC < 7f)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3((pos * 5), 0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        
        
        
        var jump = control.Movement.Jump.ReadValue<float>();
        Debug.Log(GetVerticalSpeed());
        Vector3 v = rb.velocity;
        v.y = 10;

        if(jump == 1)
        {
            rb.velocity = v;
        }

    }    
}
```

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with the rb.AddForce. Comment it out and share your results. Another thing. You should not instantiate inner methods. Its jot clean code over all but esspecially not in a fixed update. Wasted resources.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't planning on keeping that anyways, it was more of an attempt to fix this. It does help make the x and y velocity number not jitter around, but the `rb.velocity.y` still puts out high numbers moving left and right.

Do note that the high numbers only occur when touching the tilemap collider (what I'm using for ground).

Answer (score 0):

Seems the main issue was fixed by converting the height velocity to an integer using `System.Math.Round()`:

```
float vel = rb.velocity.y;
heightC = (int)System.Math.Round(vel);
```

Not sure it's the *best* solution, but it's something..